# A clean solution for dynamic entry table rows in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I'm working on a project in ASP.Net that uses the UpdatePanel to handle all AJAX requests. I'm much more familiar with using jQuery AJAX methods (and strategies) so I'm kind of stumped on finding a clean solution for the functionality I need.

Basically I need a table that allows me to dynamically add as many rows as I want using AJAX. These rows will contain text boxes whose values must be preserved by ASP.Net until I'm ready to submit the form. To further complicate matters there may already be records that exist in the database that should display as well with the values pre-populated and any changes to these fields must also be preserved.

I had started out by using a GridView and setting it's datasource to a list of the database records but unfortunately I believe this means I can't add new rows to the GridView.

Any assistance would be much appreciated. Keep in mind the solution must use ASP.Net controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I figured out a solution that seems pretty straightforward.

When the page loads I gather any relevant records from the database and perform a query expression combined with a projection select to create an anonymous type array. When the add new row button is clicked instead of trying to add the row directly or retrieve potentially old data from the database I perform a query expression on the datagrid items themselves and union a new blank item. From there it's just a simple matter of setting the datagrid data source, triggering a databind and updating the update panel.

The only question now is how to identify the rows, particularly new rows that have no database keys yet. I could devise some clever method for generating row ids but I have a feeling that ASP.Net already does this and all I need to do is associate these ids with the anonymous types.